# CSS Aspect Ratio on Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

Recently, Mozilla launched a HTML5 game called Browser Quest. In the game, if you resized the window, the canvas would also resize.

I looked more into and I saw that it was beacuse of usign CSS3 Media Queries found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

However, I still don't think I am doing it right. My canvas ID is `#canvas`. How would I go about putting it for my canvas?

my canvas specific width/height: `height:352px;` `width:512px;`

Answer (score 2):

So you don't want to define size of a canvas in CSS since you will only ever be scaling it away from its "true" size. You always want to use the `width` and `height` attributes of the Canvas instead.

But that doesn't mean you can't define it's parent's size that way. Wrap the canvas in a div and set the div's CSS width/height to 100% (or whatever you please)

In code during setup you are going to have to do:

```
// javascript pseudocode
canvas.width = theCanvasParent.clientWidth; // or whatever attribute it is, I'd reccomend putting all of those things in one giant container div
canvas.height = theCanvasParent.clientHeight;
```

Since most browsers do not fire an event when the parent div changes size, you'll simply have to check, say, every half second with a timer to see if the div has changed size. If it has, then you resize the canvas accordingly.

However there is the `onresize` event, and depending on how your page is setup this may do the trick.

In Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari, the `onresize` event is fired **only when the size of the browser window is changed.**

In Internet Explorer, the `onresize` event is fired when the size of the browser window or an element is changed.

So if the only way to change your div's size is by changing the window's size, onresize will do you just fine. Otherwise you'll need  a timer that constantly checks to see if the canvas size and div size are different (and if so, to resize the canvas).

A timer that constantly checks is what the Mozilla Bepsin team did (before Bespin became Skywriter and then merged with the Ace project, dropping all Canvas use)

Answer (score 1):

Media queries won't provide you with the functionality you seek. Their purpose is simply to limit when a particular stylesheet is applied to a page.

Furthermore, the CSS `width` and `height` properties do not adjust the actual dimensions of canvas elements. Instead, they scale the element to the requested size. In your case, I'm assuming you want the canvas to actually be a different resolution. The resolution of the canvas is specified via the DOM `width` and `height` attributes on your `<canvas>` tag.

In order to handle resizing, you will need to use `window.onresize` to capture the resize event. Your canvas code will need to then create a new canvas at the desired size and properly copy over everything from the original canvas (when you resize a canvas object its pixel data is cleared).

Answer (score 0):

As was yet pointed by Xenethyl, the most important point is to hook onresize so that you can adapt to your new canvas object size :

- adjust the canvas dimensions (the drawing area dimensions) to the canvas rendering area (clientWidth and clientHeight)
- take into account the new dimensions of the canvas for your drawing algorithms
- redraw the canvas

You don't have to make a new canvas (which would force you to rehook other event handlers).

Most of the canvas in my web applications, in order to be perfectly adjusted to the window, are managed by a dedicated class whose skeleton is here :

```
function Grapher(options) {
    this.graphId = options.canvasId;
    this.dimChanged = true; // you may remove that if you want (see above)
};

Grapher.prototype.draw = function() {
    if (!this._ensureInit()) return;

    // makes all the drawing, depending on the state of the application's model

    // uses dimChanged to know if the positions and dimensions of drawed objects have
    //  to be recomputed due to a change in canvas dimensions

}

Grapher.prototype._ensureInit = function() {
    if (this.canvas) return true;
    var canvas = document.getElementById(this.graphId);
    if (!canvas) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!$('#'+this.graphId).is(':visible')) return false;
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    var _this = this;
    var setDim = function() {
        _this.w = _this.canvas.clientWidth;
        _this.h = _this.canvas.clientHeight;
        _this.canvas.width = _this.w;
        _this.canvas.height = _this.h;
        _this.dimChanged = true;
        _this.draw(); // calls the function that draws the content
    };
    setDim();
    $(window).resize(setDim);
    // other inits (mouse hover, mouse click, etc.)
    return true;
};
```

In your case I would create a `new Grapher({canvasId:'#canvas'})` and the #canvas dimensions are defined in css (and usually adjust in complex ways to the available space).

The most interesting points are in the setDim function.